# gulp-ruby-sass: 'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am trying to run gulp-ruby-sass on windows.

I am getting the following error:

> gulp-ruby-sass: 'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

- I have successfully installed ruby on my c:\ drive (c:\Ruby193)
- I have also installed SaSS as

> gem install sass

(executed from here c:\Ruby193)

- I have also set the path to register c:\ruby193 in windows
- I am running my gulp from  c:\project\transformer\ as gulp

I am still getting this error:

gulp-ruby-sass: 'bundle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Can you please help on solving this matter?

Comment: Did you run: `gem install bundler`?

Comment: no but why do I need to ?'

Comment: Because you can't use something unless it's installed on your system, right? command: `bundle` comes from `bundler` so please run `gem install bundler` and then try again.

Comment: Mate can I request you to put this as an answer so that I can give your dues. It just works like expected!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install `bundler` gem using the following command to make `bundle` command work on your system:

```
gem install bundler
```